# Whitelisting additional Chromecast doesn't work

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have successfully witelisted my first Chromecast a while ago and my app development is well on its way. Recently I requested to add another device to my whitelist. The request went through, I've got a response. I can access my new device on port 9222, however my app fails to start the Receiver App @ URL listed in AppId when connected to new Chroemcast (it still works fine with the old one).

How can I verify that the new whitelisted device connected to the same old AppID or Developer ID?

Thanks.

Comment: Please contact us on the chromecast-updates@google.com

Comment: I did contact comcast-updates@google.com. Haven't heard back yet.

Comment: I don't see any unanswered request there; since I don't have your email address or username, I cannot specifically check on that. When did you contact us there?

Comment: Adam fixed it for me today.

Answer (score 0):

After a request to chromecast-updates@google.com the ChromeCast team fixed the problem on their side. Thanks.